# MySQL my.cnf performance tuning Need some advice

Tags: mysql, performance

Our architecture is as follows:

```html
Memory     : 132GB
CPUs       : 12
OS & Mysql : 64-bit
Disk Space : 2.0 TB
DB Engine  : MyISAM
```

i only have 1 table innodb (around 400mb)
all the rest are myISAM (around 2dg)

my server load has started going through the roof and its down to API hits my sites is getting from its users (when i turn of api if goes right down)

my sql .conf is as follows

```html
[mysqld]
innodb_file_per_table=1
bind-address=127.0.0.1


####### Performance Tweaks #######
##thread_cache_size       = 64    # Default 0
##table_open_cache        = 1024  # Default 64
##table_definition_cache  = 512 # Default 256
##max_heap_table_size     = 96M  # Default 16M
##tmp_table_size          = 96M  # Default 16M (can't be bigger than max_heap_table_size)

##key_buffer_size         = 96M   # Default 8M
##sort_buffer_size        = 256K  # Default 2M
##join_buffer_size        = 256K  # Default 128K
##read_buffer_size        = 256K  # Default 128K.
### read_rnd_buffer_size    = 512K  # Default 256K.
##concurrent_insert       = 2     # Deafult 1

##query_cache_limit       = 512K  # Default 1
##query_cache_size        = 96M  # Default 0

######### End Performance Tweaks ##########


#### ADDDED ALL BEWLO LINES ON JUNE,06,2014
# Memory usage
skip-external-locking
max_connections = 1000
max_user_connections = 3056
max_connect_errors = 999999
innodb_file_per_table = ON
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 8G
key_buffer = 1024M
#key_buffer_size = 512M
key_buffer_size = 8G
max_allowed_packet=268435456
group_concat_max_len = 12192
table_open_cache=2048
tmp_table_size = 512M
max_heap_table_size = 512M
sort_buffer_size = 32M
read_buffer_size = 32M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 20M
bulk_insert_buffer_size = 24M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 200M
query_prealloc_size = 262144
query_alloc_block_size = 65535
transaction_alloc_block_size = 8192
transaction_prealloc_size = 4096
max_write_lock_count = 8
query_cache_limit = 5M
thread_cache_size = 382
query_cache_size= 256M
# Try number of CPU's*2 for thread_concurrency (eHound has 4 CPU's)
thread_concurrency = 24

# Disable Federated by default
skip-federated

open_files_limit=10000
default-storage-engine=MyISAM
[mysqld_safe]
how variablesog-error="/var/log/mysqld.log"
pid-file="/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid"

[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet = 64M

[mysql]
no-auto-rehash

[isamchk]
#key_buffer = 512M
key_buffer = 4G
sort_buffer_size = 512M
read_buffer = 256M
write_buffer = 256M

[myisamchk]
#key_buffer = 512M
key_buffer = 4G
sort_buffer = 512M
max_allowed_packet = 14M
read_buffer = 8256M
write_buffer = 256M
sort_buffer_size = 1M
join_buffer_size = 1M
thread_stack = 192K

[mysqlhotcopy]
interactive-timeout
```

Any suggestions? Thanks folks.

After comments ove made these changes

```html
[mysqld]
innodb_file_per_table=1
bind-address=127.0.0.1


####### Performance Tweaks #######
##thread_cache_size       = 64    # Default 0
##table_open_cache        = 1024  # Default 64
##table_definition_cache  = 512 # Default 256
##max_heap_table_size     = 96M  # Default 16M
##tmp_table_size          = 96M  # Default 16M (can't be bigger than max_heap_table_size)

##key_buffer_size         = 96M   # Default 8M
##sort_buffer_size        = 256K  # Default 2M
##join_buffer_size        = 256K  # Default 128K
##read_buffer_size        = 256K  # Default 128K.
### read_rnd_buffer_size    = 512K  # Default 256K.
##concurrent_insert       = 2     # Deafult 1

##query_cache_limit       = 512K  # Default 1
##query_cache_size        = 96M  # Default 0

######### End Performance Tweaks ##########


#### ADDDED ALL BEWLO LINES ON JUNE,06,2014
# Memory usage
skip-external-locking
max_connections = 1000
max_user_connections = 3056
max_connect_errors = 999999
innodb_file_per_table = ON
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 2G
#key_buffer = 1024M
#key_buffer_size = 512M
key_buffer_size = 45G
max_allowed_packet=268435456
group_concat_max_len = 12192
table_open_cache=2048
tmp_table_size = 512M
max_heap_table_size = 512M
sort_buffer_size = 32M
read_buffer_size = 32M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 20M
bulk_insert_buffer_size = 24M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 200M
query_prealloc_size = 262144
query_alloc_block_size = 65535
transaction_alloc_block_size = 8192
transaction_prealloc_size = 4096
max_write_lock_count = 8
query_cache_limit = 5M
thread_cache_size = 382
query_cache_size= 256M
# Try number of CPU's*2 for thread_concurrency (eHound has 4 CPU's)
thread_concurrency = 24

# Disable Federated by default
skip-federated

open_files_limit=10000
default-storage-engine=MyISAM
[mysqld_safe]
how variablesog-error="/var/log/mysqld.log"
pid-file="/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid"

[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet = 64M

[mysql]
no-auto-rehash

[isamchk]
#key_buffer = 512M
key_buffer = 4G
sort_buffer_size = 512M
read_buffer = 256M
write_buffer = 256M

[myisamchk]
#key_buffer = 512M
key_buffer = 4G
sort_buffer = 512M
max_allowed_packet = 14M
read_buffer = 8256M
write_buffer = 256M
sort_buffer_size = 4M
join_buffer_size = 4M
thread_stack = 192K

[mysqlhotcopy]
interactive-timeout
```

thanks again

i have enable my sql log and i get loads of these per second, which i can see if my users using my API

```html
# Thread_id: 4273  Schema: DB_name  QC_hit: No
# Query_time: 0.402709  Lock_time: 0.000058  Rows_sent: 1  Rows_examined: 141611
SET timestamp=1431343679;
select users.*, userroles.apirequests, userroles.downloadrequests, NOW() as now from users inner join userroles on userroles.ID = users.role where users.rsstoken = 'APIKEYHERE';
```

Comment: Turn on the slowlog and see what you get.  Also, since you have a lot of RAM, change `key_buffer_size` to 20G

Comment: This question is better asked on dba.stackexchage.com.  The 8GB of for the InnoDB buffer pool seems to be a waste, if the only InnoDB table you have is a total of 400MB (including indexes). Note that concurrent DML operations are not supported on MyISAM tables; an INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE statement will obtain an exclusive lock on the   referenced MyISAM tables; and that prevents any other DML or SELECT statement from using those tables at the same time, forcing the other sessions to wait until the statement holding the lock completes.

Comment: have you run 'desc' on all the queries in question?